# Date.Time column split

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to split the Date.Time column in my data table to separate date and time columns. currently the column is as character.

this is what I already tried but it just gave me a column with 2019 dates. I don't want the year to be 2019 so doesn't work. even if it does, not sure how to get the time to a separate column

```
office$date <- as.Date(office$Date.Time, format = '%m/%d')

office$date <- as.Date(office$Date.Time, format = '%m/%d')
```

Comment: have you tried using the `format =` option of `strptime`

Answer (score 1):

Date require the year field. You can remove the year field, but the result will be a character, not the date format.

```
office$date <- as.Date(office$Date.Time, format = 'Y%/%m/%d')
office$date <- as.character(gsub("^.{5}","",office$date))
```